# Visual Web Developer Question

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Whether the download available in the following location include Service Pack 1 for Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition ?

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#%20

(Please refer Visual Studio 2008 express tab)

Please help..

Thanks

Lijo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this page you have the link (it already comes with SP1):

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2008-Visual-Web-Developer

Note: the download button will launch Web Platform Installer 2.0. From there you can select VS Web Developer.

If you want the offline installation files, click the link - All - Offline Install ISO image file. The site will give you a zip file that contains all Visual Studio express editions (Visual Web Developer Express, Visual C# Express, Visual VB.NET Express, etc - the drawback of this is the size of the download, but it's useful if you want to have the installation files around).